# Can I Specify hibernate annotated classes in hibernate.properties?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, annotations

Most or all the core hibernate configuration properties can be specified in a startup properties file, as an alternative to specifying mappings in hibernate.cfg.xml.

Is there an easy way to specify mappings of annotated classes in a properties file?

You can map annotated classes like this in the **hibernate.cfg.xml** configuration:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        ...
        <mapping class="com.annotated.classes.EntityOne"/>
</session-factory>
```

Similar configuration can be written using a properties file i.e. **hibernate.properties**

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.mapping = ???
```

What I haven't figured out is how to specify the mapping of annotated classes (entities) using the properties configuration, if this is possible.

Comment: Do you mean like you would in `YourEntity.hbm.xml`?

Comment: Similar, but my entities are heavily reliant on Annotations, and I prefer the properties file for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way to specify entities in the properties file.

I suppose you could create your own custom initialization code using [`Configuration`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) to accomplish what you are looking for. The problem with using a properties file, though, is that you cannot specify a property with a list of values unless you identify a way to split the value into a list. You would then need to write code that parses the value accordingly.